# I'm trying to call a function(for validation) on submitting a form, it works perfectly for one form but on another identical form it does not

Tags: javascript, html, css

I only started learning html, css and javascript. I'm trying to call a function to validate the form, i have two identical forms (one has some extra fields, thats it, thats the only differnce) still this method works on form1 but not on form2.
I will put the css and js internally for easy reference. Dont be discouraged by the long code most of it is repeating code.

**Form1**

```
<form name="signin" onsubmit="login(); return false" method="post">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" id="user" placeholder="type your username" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Password</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="password" placeholder="type your password" id="pass" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="#" style="font-size: 13px;">Forgot password?</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center>
                                    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="log_btn" id="log">
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

**This is the div i'm using as a popup window**

```
<div class="popup_container" id="popup_c">
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="popup" id="popupi">
        <span id="txt"></span><br><br>
        <input type="Button" id="ok_btn" onclick="ok()" value="OK" class="log_btn">
    </div>
</div>
//function to close the popup
function ok() {
    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Form1 Javascript**

```
// Login details validation
function login() {
    let us = document.getElementById('user').value.toString();
    let ps = document.getElementById('pass').value.toString();
    let expu = /[$&+~`\[,\]:\{;\}=\/?\\@#|'<>.^*()%!-]/;
    let expp = /[$&+~`\[,\]:\{;\}=\/?\\#|'<>.^*()%!-]/;
    // FOR USERNAME
    if (us.length >= 8 && us.length <= 10) {
        if (expu.test(us)) {
            document.getElementById('user').value = "";
            document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Username cannot contain symbols (except _ )";
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('user').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Username should be 8 to 10 characters !";
        return;
    }
    // FOR PASSWORD
    if (ps.length >= 8 && ps.length <= 10) {
        if (expp.test(ps)) {
            document.getElementById('pass').value = "";
            document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Password cannot contain symbols (except _ and @ )";
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('pass').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Password should be 8 to 10 characters !";
        return;
    }
    
    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "LOGIN SUCCESS !";

}
```

**Form2**

```
<form name="signup" method="post" onsubmit="signup(); return false">
                <table id="tb">
                    <tr>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Second name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="type your first name" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="sname" placeholder="type your second name" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="email" placeholder="type your e-mail" id="email" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" placeholder="letters and numbers only" id="nuser" required></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Create a passsword</td>
                        <td>Re enter passsword</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="npass" placeholder="8 characters only" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="repass" placeholder="enter password again" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <center>
                                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="log_btn" id="sub">
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

**Form2 Javascript**

```
function signup() {

let fn = document.getElementById('fname').value.toString();
let sn = document.getElementById('sname').value.toString();
let em = document.getElementById('email').value.toString();
let nu = document.getElementById('nuser').value.toString();
let np = document.getElementById('npass').value.toString();
let rp = document.getElementById('repass').value.toString();
let ex = /^[a-zA-Z]/;

if (ex.test(fn) && ex.test(sn)) { 
    document.getElementById('fname').value = "";
    document.getElementById('sname').value = "";
    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Name can only contain alphabets";
}

if (nu.length >= 8 && nu.length <= 10) {
    if (expu.test(nu)) {
        document.getElementById('nuser').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Username cannot contain symbols (except _ )";
        return;
    }
}
else {
    document.getElementById('nuser').value = "";
    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Username should be 8 to 10 characters !";
    return;
}

if (np.length >= 8 && np.length <= 10) {
    if (expp.test(ps)) {
        document.getElementById('npass').value = "";
        document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Password cannot contain symbols (except _ and @ )";
        return;
    }
}
else {
    document.getElementById('npass').value = "";
    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Password should be 8 to 10 characters !";
    return;
}

if (rp != np) {
    document.getElementById('repass').value = "";
    document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Please re_enter same password !";
    return;
}

document.getElementById('popup_c').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "SIGN UP SUCCESS !";


}
```

Comment: You need to give us a _proper_ problem description; "it is not working" is not one.

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your browsers dev tools console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that on form2 when i call the function with onsubmit, it goes to the function, but the popup div(the div i created to work as popup) can be seen for a split second then the page reloads automaticaly,  resets everything, so i use onsubmit="login(); return false". On form1 it works just fine, stops the reload of page, but on form2 it doesn't.

Comment: Basically i just want the page to NOT reload automatically when submitting the form.